# In Arkham Horror, if I lose a turn and then am drawn into a gate, am I then only delayed?

Tags: arkham-horror

I am not sure what 'losing a turn' is. Is it identical to being lost in space and time in that nothing, even monsters, affects you or fights you? Does being sucked into a gate that appears then convert me to simply being delayed?

Edit: Here is some documentation I found in the Dunwich Horror rules which implies that being drawn into a gate nullifies and previous delays and lost turns and 'resets' it in a way while retaining any possible benefits earned for the previous cost/penalty of delay/turn-loss. It likely means the accepted answer's latter section on what to do in these more complicated situations should be modified.

A link to the Dunwich Horror [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/DH_rules_english.pdf) (part of interest on page 10)

> Q: If an encounter, when failed, tells the investigator he must “stay here for 2 turns and gain 2 Clue tokens” but before the 2 turns have ended a gate appears at the location and draws the investigator into an Other World, does the investigator lose the 2 Clue tokens?
>
> A: No. The investigator immediately receives the Clue tokens when he or she agrees to meet the requirements of the encounter. If a gate opens in the meantime, the investigator is sucked through the gate and becomes delayed in the Other World. He no longer has to miss two turns if sucked through on the first – the new condi- tion (being delayed in the Other World) is in effect.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would "lose a turn" before a gate appears?

Comment: There was a location encounter that allowed me to choose to lose a turn to gain some benefit. A gate then opened as a function of the mythos card and sucked me in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Losing your turn is **different** to being delayed. Being delayed means you cannot do anything during your **movement phase**

If you have lost your turn, you skip **all phases** (including upkeep) except for the Mythos phase.

From the FAQ:

> Q: If a card tells you to “lose your next turn,” does this mean skip
> all phases, including Upkeep?
>
> A: Yes, all phases except the Mythos
> Phase. Note that this is different from being told to “stay here next
> turn,” which means you are delayed.

For your original question, based on the above, I would say you can only get sucked in to the gate that appears as part of the Mythos phase and then you have both lost a turn AND are delayed.

On your next turn, you cannot stand as that normally happens in the movement phase. You also do not have any encounters. The turn after that, you get to stand and have encounters. The following turn will be when you can actually move. This way, you still have at least 2 encounters in the other world (unless you get lucky - but to be in this situation, you need to be really unlucky)

Comment: On page 10 of the rulebook in the Mythos phase section: "If a gate opens at a location that contains an investigator, he is immediately drawn through the gate to the first area of the corresponding Other World. As a result of the sudden disorientation caused by the gate swallowing him, the investigator is delayed. Place his investigator marker on its side."

Comment: Will fix my answer,  but the premise is the same... U Do nothing other than get sucked in to a gate and get delayed as per usual

Comment: So what you're saying is the delayed side effect compounds with the lost turn and essentially makes me miss two movement phases in all?

Comment: Yes... Who said arkham was supposed to be any fun :p

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the FAQ in your answer?

Comment: The encounters aren't all carefully worded; while some say "lose your next turn" or "stay here next turn"/"delayed", I think at least a couple say "spend your next turn [doing something]". You might end up making a flavor ruling instead, depending on your play group. For example, if an encounter said "Spend your next turn reading the book. Gain 1 Skill." and you get drawn into R'lyeh, I'd say you probably put down the book, so you're not delayed, but you also don't get the skill.

Comment: @Jefromi well, if you're drawn in and normally get delayed, you probably don't get the luxury of choosing to put down the book to avoid it, unless what you meant was the additional delay of the lost turn.

Comment: Yes, I said you'd lose the delay and the reward, not avoid being drawn in. If you're sitting there for a turn (a day?) to read a book and gain something from it, and all of a sudden a portal to another world opens up and sucks you through, you're probably not just going to sit there and keep reading.